# Where does kuberenetes stores provider parameters

Tags: kubernetes

I searched a lot on google but not finding the answer. I am trying to figure out where kubernetes stores the information like node (VM), IP, Vlans (if any), file shares etc.These parameters are obtained from cloud provider and must be stored somewhere

Answer (score 0):

Kubernetes uses [etcd](https://coreos.com/etcd/) as its backing store. You can install and use `etcdctl` if you want to access it manually but you usually do not have to, except if you want to backup your whole cluster state.

Comment: Any information stored by Kubernetes in etcd is accessible via the API server. If you want to see the full resources from the API server you can add the `-o` flag to change the output type, i.e. `kubectl get pods -o yaml` to get a YAML formatted output of all the pods in the default namespace

Comment: '/ # ETCDCTL_API=3 /usr/local/bin/etcdctl  get --keys-only
Error:  range command needs arguments.
/ # ETCDCTL_API=3 /usr/local/bin/etcdctl get --keys-only
Error:  range command needs arguments.
/ # ETCDCTL_API=3 /usr/local/bin/etcdctl get --prefix --keys-only[=false]
Error: unknown flag: --keys-only[